# How can I get info why specific Android-related property was deprecated and how to replace it?

Tags: android

I have `android.R.string.no` in my code and Android Studio announces to me `'no: Int' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java`

Is there any way to check info why it was deprecated, with what it is replaced and similar info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.string#no):

> **This constant was deprecated in API level 30.**
>
> Do not use. Incorrectly matches **android.R.string.cancel** rather than "no".